# Tagsearch by Term include and exclude

Tags: mysql, sql

as the title says I want to implement a search by tags which are required or denied.

In short:

You search by a term like "Football"

The query goes

```
  SELECT 
  p.*
  FROM
  posts p
  WHERE 
  p.title LIKE '%football%'
```

Fair enough.

Now you want all Posts with the tag "win", "new" and "local" `tag_id` is provided by the search form

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
  p.*
  FROM
  posts p
  INNER JOIN posts_tags pt
  ON pt.post_id = p.id
  WHERE 
  (
    pt.tag_id IN (1,2,3)
  )
  AND p.title LIKE "%SearchTerm%"
```

Or you don't want to find anything related to "tennis"

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
  p.*
  FROM
  posts p
  INNER JOIN posts_tags pt
  ON pt.post_id = p.id
  WHERE 
  (
    pt.tag_id IN (pt.tag_id) <- Workarround for "in everything"
    AND pt.tag_id NOT IN (4) 
  )
  AND p.title LIKE '%SearchTerm%'
```

Each query seems to ignore the `IN/NOT IN` parts and solely goes for the `title LIKE` parts since I always get the same resultset.

I played arround with the brackets and tried aggregating the tag first.To avail.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine this would work:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
  p.*
  FROM
  posts p
  INNER JOIN posts_tags pt
  ON pt.post_id = p.id
  WHERE p.title LIKE '%SearchTerm%'
  AND pt.tag_id <> 4
```

As this basically states you want anything with the search term, except for the pt.tag_id not equal 4 (you may need to do '4' if it's a string).

Comment: I will try but 4 could also be multiple arguments like 4,5,6,7,x I guess it breaks there